# Where does $\cos(pi/2)$ and $\sin(pi/2)$ come from in quaternion rotation? Can you provide a simple unit quaternion rotation example?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have seen many methods of rotation such as $p' = qpq^{-1}$ and $q = \cos (pi/2),v \sin (pi/2)$ , but I became slightly confused by how a unit quaternion is performed around a vector line.

Comment: Have you looked at the wikipedia article [Quaternions and spacial rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)? What is your confusion?

Comment: Yes, but I do not really understand what p' = qpq^-1 actually represents when we perform a rotation.

Comment: The article states "it can be shown that the desired rotation can be applied to an ordinary vector **p** ... considered as a quaternion with a real coordinate equal to zero, by evaluating the conjugation of **p** by **q**: p' = qp$q^{-1}$ ... where **p'** is the new position vector of the point after rotation." What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: Where the inverse quaternion comes into play in the equation (q^-1).

Comment: Because multiplication by q and $q^{-1}$ leaves the real part of quaternions fixed.

Comment: I see, thank you.